# reply to email in message system php

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to figure out how to code the reply for my messages. This is the message DB
[image]

My question is: What to do with the reply message? Do I update the table and add the original message to it by, say, quoting it in the reply form so every time that message is brought up it brings the thread with it? Never coded one before so a little confused. For clarity, this is not a chat system just in site messaging

```
<input type='hidden' name='reply' value='[quote]<?php echo $messages; ?>[/quote]' />
```

Comment: _What to do with the reply message?_ - decide what you want to do, and do that.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? How to store threaded conversations? How to reply to stuff? How to parse replies to e-mails your system has generated?

Comment: @Dan Mainly, How to store threaded conversations.

Comment: @MikeW Whats the point of that comment? It's obviously of no use so why not just not comment?

Comment: @rogerthat The point is, that you can do whatever you want with it, but you clearly haven't decided. Your question is vague, so you get a vague response.

Comment: @MikeW My question is vague because I am not sure how to code this as I have stated so, in turn, I'm not sure what to ask. I'm looking to find out how replied messages are handled in messaging systems. Storing, displaying etc.

Comment: @rogerthat And my response is precisely to the point. _You_ decide how you handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the smoothest ways would be having another field e.g. called `reply_to` which is of the same type as the id and will be a foreign key (holding the id of the message the current one is the reply to).

```
ALTER TABLE `messages`
    ADD `reply_to` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    ADD CONSTRAINT `reply_to_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`reply_to`) REFERENCES `messages` (`id`);
```

This should alter the table (MySQL), for another DBMS you might need another code. You might want to set what is happening on update and delete there.

Now when retrieving a message from the db, you will know whether it was a reply to another one (and are able to load it because you can identifiy it) - or not.

Comment: this field will also hold the replied message?

Comment: nope, it will hold the `id` of replied message with which you can load the message itself (no redundancy)

Comment: It's also worth noting that if your system is sending and/or receiving actual e-mails, the [_Message-Id_ and _References_ headers](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/822/36.htm) may be of some use in tracking down appropriate values for the `reply_to` column.

Comment: @kingkero so replies are in another table and on clicking reply it retrieves all messages and shows them under the original? Just want to make sure I understand

Comment: @Dan Any tutorials on this? What do you mean by "actual" emails?

Comment: Kingkero's solution stores replies in the same table and uses this column to point at `id`s of other rows in this table. By "actual" e-mails, I mean e-mail messages being sent over SMTP by mail clients. So, if your system sends me an e-mail with a `Message-Id: Foo` header and I hit my "Reply" button, you'll get something back with `References: Foo`. Although I haven't got a good tutorial link handy, SMTP is a relatively simple internet protocol that's been around forever, so you can surely find something.

Comment: @Dan ok, thanks. I'll check it out and see if I can get the replies working.

Answer (score 1):

You could create another table (for replies -- call it replies?) which contains:

1) An Id

2) The content

3) the original message id the reply is related to [foreign key] (in the original email table) in terms of the convo context

This way you can separately and cleanly query and store each individual message.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing either what @kingkero said ( which seems to be easier way ) or add reply in the same table with the same fields and than format it the way you want with more code on output. It depends on where or how you intend to show replies, for getting original post you may need more complicated SQL query or code logic